# Calling CGI script from PHP not working

Tags: php, cgi

I was trying to use URL command (CGI script) of a security IP camera from PHP script.  The 
The php script is hosted in Bluehost server. I checked the cURL version and other stuff , all appears ok.     The URL command works on web browser but not in this script??

Thanks for support!

```
<?php
$url = "http://80.101.186.XX:8372/cgi-bin/viewer/recall.cgi?recall=5AB";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 8372);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT , 300);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "XXXXX:XXXXXX"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;


?>
```

Comment: what's the output of curl_exec? do you get an error message?

Comment: Maybe the camera requires a user-agent to be set? Try something like `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2');`

Comment: @OfirBaruch,  the output is blank page.

Comment: @AndrewR,  I tried adding useragent as u suggestion. still same. It takes about 20 secs then shows blank page.

Comment: OK, it was just a guess. Maybe your webhost blocks access on non-standard ports? Can you try running this locally?

Comment: @AndrewR,  Tried at local server, not working in that too. Also, the request when sent for web browser works.

Comment: Does curl_error($ch) returns anything useful?

Comment: @Mathieu, I get error in script but I could access it directly from browser. Curl error: couldn't connect to host

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!  As @AndrewR said, it is to do with webhost ( bluehost ) blocking non-standard ports. I purchased dedicated IP and requested to open required ports then all worked. Thanks all for help.